# Print values of all elements of unknown struct

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a very large struct, whose elements names and types I know.

I want to print out all values of it, but doing so would take a very, very long time to type out.

I am wondering if there is some way to print out all values knowing the members' sizes and the entire size of the structure.

Or perhaps the compiler allows something that could let me do this, something similar to **FUNCTION** macros that allow you to see the name of the function in the scope you are calling it in. I cannot put into words what exactly it would do, but if there is something that could help you know of, it would be great.

Comment: *"but doing so would take a very, very long time to type out"* Well, you clearly managed to type them all out at least once, in the struct definition. Copy/paste that, then use find-and-replace facility of your favorite text editor to convert that to a series of output statements.

Comment: *but doing so would take a very, very long time to type out.* -- Why do you need to physically type them out?  Maybe a script or usage of a good editor to generate the C++ code that outputs the struct?

Comment: use python to parse the struct and create the c++ file that will prints the data for you.

Comment: The fundamental issue is that you have to access members of a `struct` by name.  You can't access them by index.  If they are all the same type, you may want to consider using a `std::vector` inside the array with named indices.

Comment: Another idea is to implement *iterators* for your struct.  The iterator could be implemented as a *pointer to member*.  Your iterator functions would adjust the pointer to the associated member.  Speaking of associations, you could have a `std::map` or `std::vector` that would associate an index with a pointer to a structure member.  Your `print` method would iterate over all the members using the custom iterator.

Comment: So what happened with my question is I attempted to write a script (but in C++) to convert the struct into a bit printf call and then realized I can just use my IDE's debugger. Sad shit, but thanks for the answers on my question.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend you create an array, and store all the data inside of the array and in your print function loop through the array and print out the data.